# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start_time' of undefined in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the loop in javascript that is based on a json query:

```
var messages = json;
function check() {
    var startTime = messages[0].start_time;
    var content = messages[0].content;

    (...)
    messages = messages.slice(1);
    }
```

and it works fine until the messages tab is filled. But when it's empty, I'm getting errors like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start_time' of undefined
```

How can I avoid that?

The json variable content is like this:

```
[{"content":"gdsgdsgsd","start_time":"2015-10-12 16:46:36"},{"content":"aaaadsaasgdsgsd","start_time":"2015-10-12 16:46:51"}]
```

and when it's empty it's of course:

```
[]
```

This is how I fetch the json data:

```
$.getJSON('getjson.php', 
        {
            time : serverTime
        },

        function(json) {
            var messages = json;
```

and on php site I have a select query and at the end:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: That's obvious, `messages[0]` is `undefined`. Add the `json` variable content

Comment: You can avoid it by checking for it using `typeof`: `var startTime = typeof messages[0].start_time !== 'undefined' ? messages[0].start_time : '';`

Comment: @Tushar I added the json variable content

Comment: @user3766930 Is that JSON object or `string`?

Comment: How do you get the json? And dump the messages variable too

Comment: @Tushar I added the call in php in my code - is it helpful?